# Is there an optimizer in Apache Spark / MLLib that accepts a custom Loss Function that does not require a gradient?

Tags: optimization, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, gradient-descent

I am just beginning to experiment with Apache Spark / MLLib and I would like to try fitting a model that has a difficult to differentiate likelihood function. I know in R that the optimization algorithms do not require specifying a gradient (I imagine it's computed empirically / numerical derivative.)

Does such an algorithm exist for Apache Spark? Has anybody encountered it? Is there a best practice to integrate this into the current optimization library? All the R codes are compiled so I am unable to figure out exactly how those are functioning.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Scott